# How to add &amp; separator to regular expression parser for URLs

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url, escaping

The following function takes a string and returns all of the URLs contained within.  However, when the query variables are properly separated (and escaped) with &amp; it truncates at &.  How can I modify the regular expression to return the whole URL when &amp; is used?

Example :

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exvUH2qKLTU&amp;start=25
```

Becomes

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exvUH2qKLTU&
```

```
function wp_extract_urls( $content ) {
    preg_match_all(
        "#([\"']?)("
            . "(?:([\w-]+:)?//?)"
            . "[^\s()<>]+"
            . "[.]"
            . "(?:"
                . "\([\w\d]+\)|"
                . "(?:"
                    . "[^`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>«»“”‘’\s]|"
                    . "(?:[:]\d+)?/?"
                . ")+"
            . ")"
        . ")\\1#",
        $content,
        $post_links
    );

    $post_links = array_unique( array_map( 'html_entity_decode', $post_links[2] ) );

    return array_values( $post_links );
}
```

reference : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30580
Yes, this is a WordPress function, but you don't need to know anything about WordPress to help :)

Comment: Concats instead of just using the `/x` flag. Yup, looks like Wordpress. But why don't you just apply the `html_entity_decode` beforehand?

Comment: Well, this is not my function (It's WordPress core) perhaps it was for performance?